# How to force a submit button to appear at the right of a group of radio buttons (using twitter bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a group of radio buttons and a submit button. I wish to place them side by side, the group of radio buttons on the left, and the submit button aligned proportionately on the right. What is the right way to do this using twitter bootstrap?

Currently, no matter what I do, I am getting the button below the radio button group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your radio buttons and submit button are enclosed in a form tag with proper bootstrap markup, bootstrap basically provides two different form layouts.

1. form-horizontal
2. form-inline

The form layout that's ideal for this behaviour is `form-inline`. All you have to do is change your form css class from the default value to `form-inline` and override the display attribute of the `.form-inline .radio` class.

Sample HTML

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
                Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.form-inline .radio {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a working [example](http://www.bootply.com/8mUSSaYCL0#)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `form-horizontal`you can use `radio-inline` for the radio buttons..

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="">
          Radio 1
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
          Radio 2
        </label>

        <label> </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

http://bootply.com/YEfKIS6Lqa